# Doxygen struct multiple languages

Tags: c, struct, doxygen, comments

I have the following problem:
There is a struct, call it matrix

```
struct matrix {
    double** a;
    int r;
    int c;
}
```

Now I want to document my struct in german an english.

Therefore I want a brief description of all the members before the struct

```
/**
 * \~german
 * \brief description
 *
 *
```

An then I want to use a similar syntax as in functions with param.

Is there a way to do this, so I can explain the members above the code of the struct?

There is also the possibility to do

```
int r; //!< description
```

But this becomes quite confusing with multiple languages and disturbs the flow of reading the code.

thanks

EDIT:

Found a solution:

```
/**\struct matrix
 * \~German
 * \brief Beschreibung
 *
 * \~English
 * \brief description
 *
*/

struct matrix {
    double **a; //!<\~English comment \~German Kommentar
    int r;      //!<\~English comment \~German Kommentar
    int c;      //!<\~English comment \~German Kommentar
```

};

If one of the languages is on another line than its element, it does not work properly.

Comment: When I understand it well you want to generate a German and an English version of thee documentation. You probably have to generate the documentation twice and use the language possibilities as indicated by you or use \cond constructs.

Comment: I just wanted to ask, if it is possible to write it similarly to @param for functions.
Is there a way, that is similar?
Can I explain/comment the struct-members similar to function params above the struct?

Comment: If you've found your solution, post it as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally found a solution on my own:

```
/**\struct matrix
 * \~German
 * \brief Struct Beschreibung
 *
 * \~English
 * \brief Struct description
 *
*/

struct matrix {
    double **a; //!<\~English comment \~German Kommentar
    int r;      //!<\~English comment \~German Kommentar
    int c;      //!<\~English comment \~German Kommentar
};
```

If one of the languages is on another line than its element, it does not work properly.